# How to put value in a dropdown which is inside a dynamically created tr

Tags: jquery

I have created a `tr` which has a dropdown in it and i need to set the value of the select to a particular value while creating it. I tried

```
$("#"+response[i].candidate_Id).find("select").val("abc");
```

`response[i].candidate_Id` is the `id` to `tr` which i have dynamically assigned

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: share your code or reproduce the issue in snippet/fiddle

Comment: It is not an error that is not working at all.I posted to code to show what i have tried

Comment: Please add a **[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)** which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample fiddle I have created : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b78vp3e3/12/)

You need to make sure you are embedding the select to DOM before actually assigning any value to it. Your code to set the value seems correct, you just need to check order of code written.

Sample code:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.id = "myTr";
var td1 = document.createElement('td');
var td2 = document.createElement('td');
var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');
//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Volvo", "Saab", "Mercades", "Audi"];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mySelect";
td1.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = array[i];
  option.text = array[i];
  selectList.appendChild(option);
}
td2.appendChild(text2);
tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(tr);
document.body.appendChild(table);
$("#myTr").find("select").val("Audi"); // this line you can have your own id
```